# Usage of "On this case"or"in this case"

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct and why?

I think to blame you in this case is not right.

Or

I think to blame you on this case is not right.

Answer (score 4):

The idiom is always *in this/that case*, never *on this/that case*.  It's more typically *in that case*.

> John might show up.  In that case, we'll leave immediately.
>
> I think blaming you in this case is not right.

Comment: I think it might be worth pointing out that part of the confusion may be that you blame <something> *on* <someone>. A different way of saying it would be, "I think to blame this case on you is not right," or more naturally, "I don't think it's right to blame this case on you." But I agree that the heart of the question is proper use of the idiom.